# How to fix "cannot find function name" error in Angular

Tags: angular, google-maps

I'm using Angular 6 to implement a google maps based app with google maps direction API. I used following initial code in my project. But when ng serve, it says **`Cannot find name 'calculateAndDisplayRoute'`**.

I already tried with declare the function name 'calculateAndDisplayRoute' as commented above the class but seems not working either.

What is the problem here?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var google: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../../resources/css/style.min.css', '../../resources/css/bt.min.css']
})

// declare var calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) : any;

export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    initMap() {
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 7,
            center: {lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65}
        });
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

        var onChangeHandler = function() {
            calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
        };
        document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
        document.getElementById('end').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
    }

    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
        directionsService.route({
            origin: (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('start')).value,
            destination: (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('end')).value,
            travelMode: 'DRIVING'
        }, function(response, status) {
            if (status === 'OK') {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            } 
            else {
                window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
            }
        });
    }

    constructor() {

    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.initMap();
    }

}
```

Comment: You have to call the function as `this.calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using arrow function in typescript

```
var onChangeHandler = () => {
            calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
        };
```